# Convert svg to png using Canvg: "target.childnodes is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I have an SVG graphic which I want to convert to PNG and then offer it as a download. If I select the SVG and create the canvas element with jQuery I constantly get the error in the title. If I use basic javascript functions like `createElement` and `getElementById` it somehow seems to work.

So what does this error mean? If I take a look at the `canvg` source code, `target` seems to be the `canvas` in the `canvg` method (see code below). But of course it does not have any children, I did not append anything else to it.

Here is my code:

```
var svg = $('#chart')[0],
canvas = $("canvas"),
serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
svgString = serializer.serializeToString(svg);

canvas.width  = svg.width;
canvas.height = svg.height;

canvg(canvas, svgString);
```

Comment: Are you creating the canvas anywhere, because right now it looks like you only select it with `$("canvas")` and don't create it as you would with `document.createElement('canvas')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a jQuery object to canvg, you have to pass an element.

<s>What it seems to me is that canvg does check itself if you did pass a container so it has to retrieve the canvas element.</s>
<sub>*Actually they don't even do this... I don't know what they are looking into the childNodes, but they do. (if you pass an other HTMLElement, it will throw a `target.getContext is not a function` error...)*</sub>

As any other HTML elements, CanvasElement does implement the `childNodes` property, so they certainly check for `target.childNodes.length`, <s>if truthy, check for a canvas element into the list, else use the canvas.</s> This single call, if they don't check for `(target.childNodes && target.childNodes.length)` will throw the error you got.

---

So the easy fix for you is just to set `canvas = $("canvas")[0]`.